# ubuntu 14.04 LTS is making a weird strange sound like radio frequency

Tags: sound, 14.04, skype, speakers, noise

I recently updated to ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am having this issue ever since, a weird strange sound like radio frequency but this doesn't affect any other sound, I can still hear other sounds like music with this weird sound playing in the background. This comes and goes, I don't know how it is triggered and how it goes. any ideas? this happens on the laptop speakers and headphones.

Laptop Specs:

DELL - inspiron 15-3521

Memory: 3.8 GiB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-2375M CPU @ 1.50GHz × 4

Graphics Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2

OS type: 32-bit

Disk 335.3 GB

---

And the following application was running at the time this happened:

1. Google Chrome
2. Chromium Web Browser
3. Thunderbird Mail
4. NetBeans IDE 7.4
5. Home Folder
6. Text Editor
7. FileZilla
8. Skype
9. Dropbox
10. Chrome - Notifications

Comment: Could it be feedback from the mic being open for Skype? Try to set your mic to be Push-To-Talk and see if the noise remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue happened to me again so I started closing the applications one by one to eliminate the problem software, guess what is was **Skype**.

I had to close it to remove the strange sound, and I stared it again to use it.